# bbPress plugin - How do I add a forum description?

Tags: bbpress

This might be a total dummy question, but I have no idea where to enter the forum description with bbpress. I see it on plenty of other bbPress-powered forums, and the plugin is inserting `<div class="bbp-forum-description"></div>` into my table of entries, but when I create or edit a forum, I don't see a field to enter this information. Is this normal or is something strange going on with my bbPress forum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the standalone, or the plugin?

I'm not sure if there is a difference honestly, I've never touched the standalone.

Anyway, I have the plugin going

From my admin panel I have the option of adding/editing forums/topics/replies

Clicking on Add New for forum brings up a standard WP post screen

The title is the name of the forum, the post body area is the description. Is that not what you get?

Comment: Facepalm. You got it exactly right. I knew I was just being a dummy. I guess I was assuming that was something that would appear only on the forum page itself, not in the forum list. For what it's worth, they *really* need to add some documentation. Oh, and yes, I'm using the plugin.

Comment: Yup, it's just kind of being developed.... so we're all kind of stumbling through how to use it together I guess!